# How much do Linux distributions set apart from each other?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I'm planning to install Linux on a relatively old laptop. I use Python a lot, so I want to install modules and work with `virtualenvs` and this kind of stuff.

So I know that you have these `apt-get` commands in Ubuntu.
Are these the same in, let's say, Antix or MS Linux? Or would I get in big trouble using Python on Antix or MS Linux?

Comment: All Linux distribution (and Unices in general) has a package tool. Whether that is `apt`, `yum`, `pkg_add`, `pkg`, `pkgin` or something else just means that you use a different tool for a particular Unix. It's unclear what you mean by "get in big trouble".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things, you need to understand.

1. You will be probably able to get your Linux software work on any distribution.
2. `apt-get` is a tool of `apt` (Advanced Package Tool), which is a package manager designed to handle the extraction of `.deb` packages and their dependencies from repositories into your system. `apt` is used mostly in Debian based distributions.
3. `apt` is not the only package manager. There are more of them, you can use [search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=package+managers+for+linux&atb=v213-7&ia=web) for this.
4. If I were you, I wouldn't go for MS Linux. It's a dead distribution.

Answer (score 0):

For an oldish laptop, you will have to restrict yourself to a minimalistic distribution/setup (no fancy window manager, go for one of the minimal ones like XFCE or less). Disk space should not be a big problem, a full distribution takes a few (dozen) GiB of disk space. Memory is critical, most distributions today ask for at least 4GiB (but my 8 year old netbook with 2GiB works RAM fine with Fedora -- but no Firefox, lightweight window manager only, any compilation takes ages).